# photoshop and adobe stock images

Tags: adobe-photoshop

alright, ive got a purchased stock image of a white tshirt with a white background. i dont need or want the background. what i do want is to do a color fade half way up my shirt and i cant see to edit it or get the image edited. HELP[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEc0w.png)#I DONT HAVE A CLUE WHAT IM DOING

Comment: Sorry but.. what are you asking?? Did you purchase the image or merely copy it from your browser window? Do you know how to edit it but are unable to? Or do you not know how to edit the image?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have got a version without text Adobe Stock - paid versions should come without watermarks.  But you have purchased a JPG version of the image. JPG cannot have transparent background.

I'm afraid they do not give your money back nor change the image to PNG or other version which has transparent background, but nothing should prevent you to try to ask (no guarantee do they answer or is other than JPG even available).

JPGs have no layers. Double-click the background in the layers panel of Photoshop to convert the background to editable layer. Make a few layer duplicates to try different things. Close in the layers panel all but one of the copies and start your background removal attempts.

At first try to select with the magic wand the background with 0 or 1 tolerance and having option "contiguous" ON. Press DEL. If the result is not good enough you can undo and try if Select > Refine Edge adjustments could make the selection better (without seeing cannot have no idea what adjustments are needed)

Photoshop also has some advanced background removal functionality. I have no idea does it work with contrast this low. Check tutorials like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWSa5SYzZu8

I'm afraid that you must bite the bullet and draw a path around the shirt, convert it to selection, invert the selection and then and delete the background. Drawing path is the last resort, but it's needed harmfully often. Some people have developed their path drawing incredibly fast and accurate for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full tutorial, but you could make a simple edit using fairly basic steps as as follows:

1. Select the T-Shirt using the Quick Selection tool <kbd>W</kbd>
2. Refine the selection using the *Select and Mask* mask button in the tool options along the top, then increase the Smoothing slider
3. Set *Output to: Layer mask* from the dropdown, hit OK.
4. Create a new layer above the t-shirt layer by clicking the New Layer icon in the layers panel
5. Choose the Gradient tool <kbd>G</kbd>, choose a gradient from the dropdown in the tool options along the top. Click and drag to fill the layer with a gradient, and set the layer blending mode to *Multiply*
6. Clip the gradient layer to the masked t-shirt layer by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+clicking between the two layers.

Example

[image]

**Note:** For absolute beginners this may be a challenge if they know absolutely nothing about Photoshop.  Before you try this, you should probably look for tutorials on the basics of using Photoshop. There are lots on youtube.  Search for photoshop background removal tutorials, and perhaps look for tutorials that explain the basics such as using layers, layer masks, layer blending modes, how to understand the user interface, etc.